# Routing Internet Traffic through VPN tunnel

Tags: routing, openvpn, ipv6, ipv4

I am relatively new to the topic, so please do not mind if I ask simple (or stupid) questions. 
I own a Raspberry Pi 3B and installed and configured an OpenVPN server on it. 
Therefore I followed this openvpn community guide: https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/
I am using a Windows machine to connect to this server, which works perfectly fine. I tried to configure the server, such that my IPv4 internet traffic is routed through the tunnel. The problem is, during connection to the VPN server is established, IPv4 websites are not loading at all. Furthermore IPv6 traffic still slips through, such that IPv6 websites load as usual. 
Please find server config, client config, iptables rulesets and IP routing table attached. In addition to this, I configured the NAT according to the community guide with the command

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

So the problem in the end is the correct routing. Thank you all in advance for your help!

Cheers,
Patrick

P.S.: 192.168.2.1 is the IP of the W-Lan router my Pi is connected to via ethernet.

## Server config

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/server/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/server/dh.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/server/ta.key 0 
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
push "redirect-gateway local def1"
push "dhcp-options DNS 10.8.0.1"
```

## Client config

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 192.168.2.129 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 3
redirect-gateway local def1
```

## IPv4 rules

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_INPUT_denied: "
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_FORWARD_denied: "
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m udp --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m tcp --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_OUTPUT_denied: "
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
```

## IPv6 rules

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
COMMIT
```

## IP Routing table

```
Target       Router            Genmask             Flags     MSS Window irtt Iface
0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1       0.0.0.0             UG          0 0            0   eth0
10.8.0.0     10.8.0.2          255.255.255.0       UG          0 0            0   tun0
10.8.0.0.2    0.0.0.0          255.255.255.225     UH          0 0            0   tun0
192.168.2.1   0.0.0.0          255.255.255.0       U           0 0            0   eth0
```

Comment: Are you using `push "redirect-gateway def1"` on server?

Comment: Yes, I am using it

Answer (score 0):

Is the IP routing table from your windows machine for client?
I do quite get understand why they recommand "def1" thing.
To me, your question is fairly simple, your Windows client and your VPN server are both on 192.168.2.0/24 gw 192.168.2.1 and you would be better off setting the default gw as virtual IP of your vpn server inside the tunnel, check

```
ip addr
```

or simply add log /var/ovpn.log to your config and check the real IP it is.
and secondly set 192.168.2.1 as the gw for net 192.168.2.0/24
Once you get this routing table set up,
Your Windows machine will find that 192.168.2.1 to reach to your VPN server, and any other traffic outside 192.168.2.0/24 goes to the virtual IP of that server for routing.

Comment: The shown Routing table is obtained on the Pi when the vpn Server is running. Therefore I use the *netstat -nr* command.

What Do you mean? Which address in the server config and Client config has to be changed?

When I Do *ip addr* on my Pi I get IPs for all Interfaces, including the tun0 interface. Thanks already for your help!

Comment: push "redirect-gateway local def1"
push "dhcp-options DNS 10.8.0.1" These two commands mean to alter the Windows routing table to use the virtual IP in the tunnel on the other end. I do not how this worked but I believe setting the default gateway to that makes more sense, at least can be done on Linux.

Comment: I added these 2 command to both the Windows Client config file and Server config file. Nothing changes. Maybe another interesting thing to note: when I leave out the *local* before def1 in the config files I can surf the Internet, but my public ip does not change.

Comment: Would it help if I also post the routing table of the client machine?

Comment: ` traceroute to google.com (172.217.16.206), 64 hops max 
- 1 10.8.0.1 3.551ms 6.132ms 3.232ms`
so your ping does go to the router of the tunnel!

Comment: Yes it seems like, but it does not go through it and stops there

Answer (score 0):

You are rejecting traffics in the forward chain of your iptables unconditionally.

In case it the limit is really what you want, it should probably be done like this:

```
-N WHATEVER
-A WHATEVER -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_FORWARD_denied: "
-A WHATEVER -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 3/min -g WHATEVER
```

So that you won't be rejecting unconditionally. I have no idea if the the limit is sane / what you intend though.

Also note that even if it isn't what you want and you ditched the whole thing, you need to make sure IP forwarding is not only allowed (in iptables) by enabled (with sysctl).

P.S. Not sure how to avoid "IPv6 leak". That may be a system specfic problem though (i.e. not an OpenVPN problem).

Comment: Thank you for that comment. I even tried everything I posted above, without setting Firewall rules to the iptables, but I didnt work either. So I guess, it has nothing to Do with my iptables, but I might also be wrong. How do I enable IP forwarding? And what does it do in the end? This is very interesting

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux Basically turning a machine into "router mode", allowing traffics from one interface being routed out from another (instead of just reaching the machine itself). In this case the interfaces involved would be the VPN tunnel and the physical NIC.

Comment: I checked this on my Pi and IP forwarding is enabled.

Comment: Btw you pushed the Pi as DNS server but does it forward DNS requests in any way? Try to ping a public IP (e.g. 8.8.8.8) to see if it's actually a DNS problem.

Comment: When I am connected to the VPN with my Windows Client ping 8.8.8.8 ends with a connection time out. This is only the case when I redirect-gateway local. When I leave out the local I can ping e.g. 8.8.8.8. But my public IP Adress is not changed when I Check it online

Comment: Further checking I must say, that I can ping 8.8.8.8, but not google.com, because the hostname was not found

Comment: Regarding `ping`. It shows there is connection between you and a public ip, but `tracert <public ip>` (on Windows) or `traceroute <public ip>` (on Linux) will show whether or not an ip package is actually being forwarded via VPN or using the normal way out through your router. Next up: You computer says it cant resolve Google.com. What ip address is used as your DNS server?

Comment: `push "dhcp-options DNS 10.8.0.1"`

Comment: On my linux client machine the client config contains:
push "dhcp-options DNS 10.8.0.1"
redirect-gateway def1

Here the following outputs of traceroute:

Comment: traceroute to google.com (172.217.16.206), 64 hops max

- 1   10.8.0.1  3.551ms  6.132ms  3.232ms 

- 2   *  *  * 

- 3   62.155.244.28  8.291ms  7.344ms  8.133ms 

- 4   62.154.18.34  14.459ms  14.620ms  14.406ms 

- 5   80.150.170.30  14.263ms  15.232ms  13.371ms 

- 6   108.170.251.193  14.915ms  14.156ms  14.746ms 

- 7   216.239.40.235  14.737ms  17.478ms  15.386ms 

- 8   172.217.16.206  15.115ms  13.720ms  15.701ms

Comment: traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max
-1   10.8.0.1  3.431ms  3.021ms  6.034ms 
-2   *  *  * 
-3   62.155.244.28  8.704ms  16.278ms  22.492ms 
  -4   217.5.118.30  17.907ms  23.074ms  16.844ms 
  -5   62.157.250.46  22.319ms  16.323ms  27.686ms 
  -6   *  *  * 
  -7   8.8.8.8  14.281ms  15.043ms  13.892ms

Comment: Okay, just forget the rest I was writing. I forgot the "local" keyword in the redirect-gateway part. I am able now connect to the internet, but my IP is not hidden. So on ifconfig.me I still see my routers public ip

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be on the Windows 10 client. By default, the interface metric for both the physical network adapter and the VPN virtual network adapter are set to Automatic. You need to uncheck Automatic and enter a value of 50 for the physical adapter and 25 for the VPN virtual adapter. Then, open a command prompt with Run as Administrator and issue the command `ipconfig /flushdns`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the push router configuration does well for the client, that your Windows machine knows to and is able to find the VPN server at 10.8.0.1 as a router.

And that your ping reaches the google.com and 8.8.8.8 but the question is why it does not echo back?

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max 
-1 10.8.0.1 3.431ms 3.021ms 6.034ms 
-2 * * * 
......
-7 8.8.8.8 14.281ms 15.043ms 13.892ms
```

I guess the main reason is that the masquerade in iptables masquerade the source IPv6 from your Windows machine by the IPv6 of your Rasberry Pi, and those websites refuse to respond to any IPv6 address.

A further diagnose on the packet out from your Pi machine is helpful, you may use `ip addr` or `ifconfig` to check the [netcard's name] beginning with "eth" and  address after "inet"(ipv4) & "inet6" section(ipv6). And you can check the real traffic out from your Pi while you ping from the Windows client.

```
tcpdump icmp -nn -i [netcard's name] -v
```

And if you find that the outgoing traffic gets the source address of your Pi's ipv6, indeed it is the cause. To fix you should substitute the masquerade clause(delete it) by explicitly specifying SNAT (changing source IP) to its ipv4 address:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT -to [Pi's ipv4 address]
```

Comment: Thank's for the tip. So I performed
"sudo tcpdump icmp -nn -i eth0 -v" on my Pi during the connected windows client was pinging. While I was pinging 8.8.8.8 tcpdump showed me in and out going traffic and worked fine. When I tried to ping google.com this failed with a connection time-out on my windows client and tcpdump on my Pi did not show any output.

Comment: If pinging an IP on internet works while a domain name like "xxx.com" fails, the problem is limited to Domain Name Solution. I guess the "10.8.0.1" does not work as expected. If you ping a domain name, the normal packets will usually start with an ARP request and the response to resolve that domain name to a public IP before the real Ping IP started. If no ARP request out, "10.8.0.1" is wrong, and if only no ARP response back, check firewall settings to block ARP response.

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: "sudo tcpdump udp or icmp -nn -i eth0 -v" on Pi before you start a ping on a whatever.com from your Windows machine after establishing the VPN tunnel.

Comment: So, I played around a bit. On my Windows machine I used "tracert 8.8.8.8" . During connection to the VPN the connection to the Standard gateway fails. Even the first connection Times out. Without vpn connection the package first reaches my WLAN Router and then hops to 8.8.8.8 over several Checkpoints

Comment: So as far as I can see it from here when I establish connection to my vpn All the traffic is routed to the VPN Server. But the vpn Server does not manage to forward this traffic through my gateway

Comment: Your WLAN router @ 192.168.2.1, your Pi (VPN Sever Router) @192.168.2.129, but where is your Windows machine located? Check ipconfig in cmd and look for ipv4.

Comment: My Windows machine is at 192.168.2.137

Comment: First of all, check if the WLAN router would serve your Pi or not. Do a ping on Pi to an IP and do a ping to a domain name like google.com. Since three of the machines are in the same subnet it is possible that the returning traffic would be handed by your WLAN router directly to your Windows machine 192.168.2.1->192.168.2.137. This mistake happened because as your Windows machines sends out a package, even through the tunnel in Net 10.8.0.0/24 it says it is from 192.168.2.137. You can do a tcpdump on the tunnel out point on Pi : tcpdump -i tun0 (check ip addr to determine if it is tun0)

Comment: Or simply use `tcpdump icmp` on the Pi while tunnel is up and your Windows machine pings out. You must check if the source address on the left is whether "192.168.2.137" or "10.8.0.x" assigned to the VPN client on your Windows machine.

Comment: I have managed to solve the connection issue. I just forgot the "local" keyword during redirect gateway. I am connected to the VPN now with my Windows machine and use tcpdump on tun0. When I now e.g. surf to Facebook.com I can see the querys and replies from Facebook on the tcpdump output. So I can be sure everything is going through tun0 right? **BUT** when I visit ifconfig.me I still See my routers public IP

Comment: In Addition, when I am connected to the VPN and perform tracert Google.com on my Windows I see the following: First hop is to the VPN Server at 10.8.0.1. Second hop is to the WLAN Router and following hops go through the Internet until the packages reach Google.com. So for me it seems the stuff now goes through the Tunnel into the Web. But why is my public ip still unchanged?

Comment: So what is the correct clause of redirect gateway in the config file? The reason why your public IP would not change is that both your Pi and Windows server are in the same private net hosted by WLAN router, who only gains a public IP from your telecom through PPPoE dial. So if you want to really change public IP you have to rent a server and a public IP (this time must be different one) on cloud and set it as the VPN server.

Comment: The correct Clause in the client config is: "redirect gateway local def1 bypass-dhcp" and "push DHCP-options DNS 192.168.2.1"

Comment: Are there any other possibilities instead of renting another Server outside my network? If not which Server hosting Server would you recommend? Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: "Are there any other possibilities instead of renting another Server outside my network? " - Just search "VPN" online and you will find a host of VPN services that charges monthly fee. All you need to do is download their applications and pay the bill.